# Sort a list of filenames alphabetically but grouped by their extension

Tags: notepad++, sorting

I have a text file which contains filenames with their extension.

*apple.c

orange.hpp

plum.h

mango.c

banana.cpp

grapes.hpp*

I want the above text sorted alphabetically but grouped based on their extensions: i.e,

*apple.c

mango.c

banana.cpp

plum.h

grapes.hpp

orange.hpp*

How can I do this in Notepad++?

I tried the TextFX plugin, Linesort Plugin and column editor. Linesort plugin has an option to sort lines from right but the output is still not correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin ‘SQL’. It requires a header to be used properly. I've added the header so the text now looks as follows

```
COLUMN1.COLUMN2
apple.c
orange.hpp
plum.h
mango.c
banana.cpp
grapes.hpp
```

Choose N++ Menu --> Plugins --> SQL --> Start

**SQL statement**: SELECT COLUMN1 c1,COLUMN2 c2 FROM data ORDER BY c2,c1
**Delimiter**: .

Click on 'execute SQL' button.

A new file will be created with this content:

```
SQL Plugin 1.0.1025
Query         : select column1 c1,column2 c2 from data order by c2,c1
Sourcefile    : new 6
Delimiter     : .
Number of hits: 6
===================================================================================
Query result:
apple.c
mango.c
banana.cpp
plum.h
grapes.hpp
orange.hpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides non-standard plugins, there is also way using standard **TextFX** plugin which many users find shipped with their N++. It is not amazingly elegant, but it works:

```
apple.c
orange.hpp
plum.h
mango.c
banana.cpp
grapes.hpp
```

1. Use find/replace to prepend extensions before file names

- Find what: `^(.*\.(.*))$`
- Replace with: `\2\t\1`
- Search mode: **Regular Expression**
- ". matches newline": Unchecked

```
c   apple.c
hpp orange.hpp
h   plum.h
c   mango.c
cpp banana.cpp
hpp grapes.hpp
```

2. **Edit → Line Operations → Sort**

```
c   apple.c
c   mango.c
cpp banana.cpp
h   plum.h
hpp grapes.hpp
hpp orange.hpp
```

3. Use find/replace to remove temporary column

- Find what: `^.*\t(.*)$`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Search mode: **Regular Expression**
- ". matches newline": Unchecked

```
apple.c
mango.c
banana.cpp
plum.h
grapes.hpp
orange.hpp
```

Comment: You can use *Edit → Line Operations → Sort* instead of TextFX.

Comment: @root – sure, this answer is now obsolete. TextFX is no longer viable and continually, the *Edit* menu was enhanced with sorting abilities.

Comment: I suggested an edit to make the answer valid again. The edit is being reviewed.